# why QListWidget content are not showing up

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I am trying to populate a window QListWidget but when I run the code the empty QDialog Window shows up .

```
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   app.setStyle("cleanlooks")

   dialogWin=QtGui.QDialog()
   dialogWin.setWindowTitle("QDialog Window")
   dialogWin.setGeometry(100,230,270,210)
   data=QtCore.QStringList()
   data << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four" << "five"
   layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
   layout.setMargin(1)
   listWidget=QtGui.QListWidget()
   layout.addWidget(listWidget)
   layout.addStretch(1)
   dialogWin.show()
```

the windows shows up empty!!! why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not telling layout what widget it belongs to. Try this:

```
layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(dialogWin)
```

Comment: well let instead of QDialog I have QMainWindow, and QMainWindow already has its own layout then how do we add some widget, button or label to QMainWindow ?